# Try keys in a dictionary until one works - python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, exception

My dictionary contains keys (which may or may not repeat) and values (which are all unique). I get an exception error when my key, value pair does not work. When I get an exception, I would like to move to the next matching key, and try it's value.  If none of them work, reach "finally" exception handler and just continue to next key.

Below is sort of the logic laid out, except my current logic would only try one other key possibility when I would like to exhaust all key options before reaching "finally".

```
for currentFile, originalFile in filepath_dictionary.items():
try:
    relocateSource(currentFile, originalFile)
except:
    # (Some logic which tries the next key, value pair in which the key matches the current key
finally:
    print 'Could not relocate file: ' + currentFile
```

Comment: Your keys don't repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think that your keys repeat, but your values don't, then you have your data structure wrong, because dictionary keys are unique.

There are two possible solutions:

- Reverse your dictionary structure so that the unique filenames are keys and the repeating filenames are the values.
- Make each value of your dictionary a list of filenames, so that the several unique filenames are associated with the repeating filename. In other words, you represent the repetition of the repeating filename by associating it with several unique filenames instead of only one.

Taking the second option gives you something like this:

```
for current_file, original_files in filepath_dictionary.items():
    for original_file in original_files:
        try:
            relocate_source(current_file, original_file)                
            break
        except:
            pass
    else:
        print 'Could not relocate file: ', current_file
```

Comment: Yes!  Thank you.  So simple, I just had an incorrect understanding of dictionary keys!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In a Python dictionary, all keys are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should keep values of repeated keys in a list and simply search in that list if exception raises.

```
dct = {key1: [val2_k1, val2_k1], key2: [val2_k2]}
```